# Any possible threats of making a private key of a testnet (Ropsten) available to public

Tags: dapp-development, testnets, private-key, vulnerability, ropsten-revival

I'm about to publish a sample Dapp (with source code) and would like to provide an account and its private key available in the source code to make the life easy for anyone trying to use it. This account is created in Ropsten-revival and hence no Ether or any other known valuable info attached to it. I know Ropsten is vulnerable for D/DOS and just wanted to make sure whether I'm exposing myself or the testnet to any unknown dark side.

Comment: Why sharing an address/private_key if it is testnet. Users can get ether extremely easely.

Comment: Trying to minimise the resistance for anyone to use it. I use metamask for ether, but even that involves few steps (install metamask, find a faucet etc)

Comment: There is no problem doing that. But if someone is using tesnet, it already means this perso has experience (at least a minimum). Lambda user just here for crypto kitties won't even know about ropsten I guess.